# Android unable to create files directory

Tags: android

On Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2), after installing, I click the app, and it crashes. Crash stack is

```
08-18 13:58:48.191 10816-10851/com.example.galina.demo W/ContextImpl: Unable to create files directory /data/data/com.example.galina.demo/files
08-18 13:58:48.191 10816-10816/com.example.galina.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.galina.demo, PID: 10816
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.galina.demo.MainApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4752)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.cll.android.AndroidCll.<init>(AndroidCll.java:42)
    at com.example.util.telemetry.CllLogger.<init>(CllLogger.java:113)
    at com.example.util.TTLCoreImpl.initialize(TTLCoreImpl.java:134)
    at com.example.util.core.TTLCore.initialize(TTLCore.java:24)
    at com.example.galina.demo.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:25)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The MainApplication.java is doing initiating work, and it has a lot codes...
The line at AndroidCll.java:42 is

```
String dataPath = context.getFilesDir().getPath();
```

with `context` null. 
    `context` is passed in by getApplicationContext() from MainApplication.onCreate().

The reason why context is null is **vm shutdown caused by uncaught exception**, this exception is related to `Unable to create files directory /data/data/com.example.galina.demo/files`
I checked directory /data/data/, there's no folder `com.microsoft.mmx.sdkdemo`. It doesn't happen every time, but at a high possibility. I test other apps on this device, there's no problem. It's very weird why it fails to create this directory.

Comment: Attach your `MainApplication.java` file

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.cll.android.AndroidCll.<init>(AndroidCll.java:42)`

Check object null or notnull

Comment: share your code

Comment: have added your application class in manifest file name tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inform Android that your application needs to write to external storage by adding a uses-permission entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: it's not an external storage.

Comment: then use internal storage.